# How can we access Settings > Safety & emergency on Android via ADB commands?

Tags: adb, settings

How can we access Settings > Safety & emergency via ADB commands?

I tried the below commands but none are working.

1.

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.emergency.EmergencyDashboardFragment

Starting: Intent { cmp=com.android.settings/.emergency.EmergencyDashboardFragment }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.emergency.EmergencyDashboardFragment} does not exist.
```

2. ```
   emu64xa:/ # adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings -e :android:show_fragment com.android.settings.emergency.EmergencyDashboardFragment
   ```

This only opens the settings, but not Settings > Safety & emergency

Comment: Where did you got the value `EmergencyDashboardFragment` from? Use an AndroidManifest.xml viewer to check the real activity names of the settings app.

Comment: From the Logcat. I open the 'Safety and emergency' sub settings manually and monitored the logcat. The logcat message is below:

"12-29 16:12:55.456  5268  5268 D SettingsActivity: Switching to fragment com.android.settings.emergency.EmergencyDashboardFragment"

Comment: But a fragment is not an activity you can call. Check `AndroidManifest.xml` to get the activity values.

Comment: I looked over 100 activities, but couldn't find one that opens Settings > Safety & emergency via ADB.

This is how I got the list of activities:
'adb shell dumpsys package | grep com.android.settings/.Settings | grep Activity'